# El archivo '.../node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' no es un módulo

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-material, angular-cli

muy buenas a todos. Estoy trabajando con Angular y todo funciona ok en mi proyecto que empecé en mi PC pero el problema viene cuando intento hacerlo funcionar cuando hago el `clone` desde bitbucket. El `clone` se hace perfecto y hago el `npm install` y al parecer no da errores visibles pero al hacer el `ng-serve` lanza miles de errores como el descrito en el titulo:

```
ERROR in src/app/inscripcion/historial/productos/productos.component.ts(2,71): error TS2306: File '.../app/profile/profile.component.ts(5,29): error TS2306: File '.../node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

y un error de compilación. Probé instalando de nuevo angular material, borrando la carpeta `node_modules` y haciendo el `npm install` otra vez pero nada de eso funciona.

Dejo mas info sobre package.json y Angular:

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "github:angular/animations-builds",
"@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
"@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"rxjs": "~6.4.0",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
"@angular/cli": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.15.0",
"typescript": "~3.4.3"
}
```

Angular ng v

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.6
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.3
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.6
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.6
@angular/animations               9.0.0-next.7
@angular/cdk                      8.2.0-f537fbafb-f537fba
@angular/cli                      8.0.6
@angular/material                 8.2.0-f537fbafb-f537fba
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.6
@schematics/angular               8.0.6
@schematics/update                0.800.6
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.30.0
```

Tambien me da error en el `import { ... } from '@angular/material';`

Agradeceria que alguien me pudiese ayudar. No veo info en internet sobre esto. 
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué intentas importar desde`'@angular/material'`? Es posible que esas clases no estén ahí

Comment: `import { 
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatDividerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatBadgeModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatDialogModule
} from '@angular/material';` <- por ejemplo

Comment: sin embargo, si importo algo desde `'@angular/material/XXX'` si que lo coge bien y no da el fallo de subrayado en rojo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bien, después de estar investigando y mirando código como un loco me dí cuenta de que al importar cualquier componente de angular material desde `@angular/material` directamente esto daba un error `".../@angular/material" is not a module` pero al importarlos desde sus respectivas carpetas como por ejemplo `"@angular/material/button"` ya no salta ese error. Tuve que cambiar todos los import de `app.module.ts` y también de todos mis componentes donde los utilizaba.

No se si habrá una solución mejor pero esto es lo que me ha servido a mi por el momento. si alguien sabe otro método por favor lo publique.

Gracias

Comment: Es que es como se debe hacer, las clases no están declaradas desde la raíz del módulo, sino en distintas carpetas

Answer (score 1):

Para poder realizar multiples import como lo deseas tiene que existir un index.ts que contenga los export de todos modulos contenidos en esa carpeta.
Para tú caso te da error al realizar el import { ... } from '@angular/material' ya que este no cuenta con un index.ts que contenga los modulos de ese directorio.

Answer (score -1):

tiene que mirar varias cuestiones en si
tiene mirar la version de angular global

```
ng --version
```

este actualiza y tambien mira la version local `node_modules/@angular/core/package. json` te va aparecer el Json

```
version": "13.1.1"
```

a veces tene la version local mas desatualizada que lo global o visiversa no se tu caso

pero sin salime de la pregunta
`node_modules` fijate que no tenga la carpeta de Material y tambien una cdk y otra que dice animation revisa que no tenga eso

por último podemo forzar la descarga de material

```
//acá le especificamos la version que deseamos
npm install  @angular/material@8.2.3 --force
```